# Get all types that inherit generic constraint in Ninject

Tags: generics, types, interface, ninject, type-constraints

I have generic type `IMyGeneric<T> where T : IBase`.

How can I get all types inherit `IMyGeneric<T>` in ninject?

I tried this:

```
this.kernel.GetAll<IMyGeneric<IBase>>();
```

but that is not working and its returning 0 results.

I could get everything that is inheriting `IBase` and then `foreach` all types and use `this.kernel.Get(type)` but then I would have `IEnumerable<object>` and not `IEnumerable<IMyGeneric<IMyInheritedType>>` and would not be able to cast and return then as specific type e.g. `IEnumerable<IMyGeneric<IBase>>` because I get error on cast.

Comment: Converting an `IMyGeneric<T>` to an `IMyGeneric<IBase>` will only work when the interface is defined as variant type: `IMyGeneric<out T>`, but even then I don't think that Ninject actually supports this. So even if you register a list of different types of `IMyGeneric<T>`, Ninject will probably not get these types for you.

Comment: Any other way to get all implementations based on constraint? Or create IBaseConstraint (just for constraint) and then get everything via IBase? Although I don't really like that idea.

Comment: You might want to show more the actual implementation you have for us to provide you with feedback about how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject only supports injecting types which are specifically registered. With two exceptions:

1. if the requested type is instanciatable (for example when you request `FooClass` and `FooClass` contains an accessible constructor).
2. open generic bindings (you have a closed generic, so it doesn't help here)

Means if you want to resolve several `IMyGeneric<IBase>` you will need to register several:

```
Bind<Apple>().To<IMyGeneric<IBase>>();
Bind<Pear>().To<IMyGeneric<IBase>>();
```

or, if these types need to be resolvable by multiple types:

```
Bind(typeof(Apple)).To(typeof(IMyGeneric<IBase>), typeof(IMyGeneric<Apple>));
```

Instead of manually defining all the bindings you can make use of the [Conventions Extension](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) and use a custom [`IBindingGenerator`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/IBindingGenerator.cs) to create the bindings.
Or of course you could also write your own reflection based helper.